# Image fade to new image on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the background image of a div when a user hovers on an item on the page. I know there has to be a better way to do this.... This is what I have now.

'#11' is the div that will be hovered over.

'#treeBG' is the div whose background image should change

Current image is bg.jpg and I want that to fade out and blur.jpeg to fade in, in its place.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#11').hover(function() {
    $('#treeBG').css('background-image', 'url("blur.jpeg")');
        $('#treeBG').css('width', '100%');
        $('#treeBG').css('background-size', 'cover');
        $('#treeBG').css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
  }, function() {
  // on mouseout, reset the background image
    $('#treeBG').css('background-image', 'url("blur.jpeg")');
  });
});
```

I have the image changing no problem, I just want it to have a fade transition to look nicer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using css transitions! `transition: background 2s ease-in-out;`

Comment: I tired adding that, but I don't think I had the code right inside the script. Can you type it as it should be? @FernandoChavezHerrera

Comment: I think you need to add that separately within your css style sheet.

Comment: Please select an answer if mine helped.

Comment: @fernandoChavez I cannot select your response as an answer. Can you try to repost it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#treeBG').fadeOut('slow',function(){
    $('#treeBG').css('background-image', 'url("blur.jpeg")');
    $('#treeBG').css('width', '100%');
    $('#treeBG').css('background-size', 'cover');
    $('#treeBG').css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
    $('#treeBG').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Try to do so

Comment: That works, but I need it start once '#11' is hovered on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/y4orwqqu/1/

First off you div id's should not start with a number. So I updated it to be text.

```
$(function() {
  $('#eleven').hover(function() {
    $('#treeBG').css('background', '#000000');
        $('#treeBG').css('width', '100%');
        $('#treeBG').css('background-size', 'cover');
        $('#treeBG').css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
  }, function() {
    // on mouseout, reset the background image
    $('#treeBG').css('background', '#FFFFFF');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case #11 numerical id didn't work... so i changed #eleven. Try this code:

```
$('#eleven').hover(function(){

   $('#treeBG').fadeOut('slow',function(){
       $(this).css({
      'background-image': 'url("blur.jpeg")',
      'width' : '100%',
      'background-size' : 'cover',
      'background-repeat':'no-repeat'
    }).fadeIn('slow');

  });
  },function(){
     $('#treeBG').css({
      'background-image': 'url("blur.jpeg")'});
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pure Css is the most clean way to do that:

**style.css**

```
<!-- Change #11 for #eleven or whatever which don't start with numbers. Check  out how to use IDs in Css. I recommend you use classes instead Ids by using styles -->
#eleven {
     background-color: blue;
     padding: 1%;
     width: 50%;
     text-align: center;
     color: white;
 }
<!-- This syntaxis says: change #threeBG when #eleven is hover -->
#eleven:hover ~ #treeBG {
     background-image: url("blue.png");
     width: 100%;
     background-size: cover;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```